# Query over the result of 'DESCRIBE' statement in Impala

Tags: impala

I have to use the column names which I can get from `Describe` statement in impala, something like-

`Select name from Describe tablename;`

The problem is- I can't query over the result of `Describe` statement, it shows error. Similarly, `Show` statement result can't be queried. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You could use Spark with a `HiveContext`. You could use Java code with a JDBC connection. You could use a shell script, running the `describe` query via Impala shell, then parsing the result with `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: How about connecting to the metastore?

Comment: I agree Impala really should support this, imagine something like: select name from (describe tablename) x; This would work with the given syntax...